# How to make bathroom tiles non slippery

Tags: bathroom, tile

We currently have the typical floor tiles in our bedroom and bathroom. I dont know if they are ceramic or porcelain. The problem is the bathroom floor can get very slippery when wet (and when the bath mats are not in the bathroom (washed/dryed)). Are there any ways I could make the tiles in our bathroom non slippery ? 

Installing grab rails is an option am considering at the moment. But any other ideas ?

Comment: throw a old towel on the floor

Answer (score 2):

A few products on the market (depending on the type of tile). They are sealers that when applied properly, etch the face of the tile and add skid resistance when wet. They do not change the appearance of the tile at all (as always, test an inconspicuous area and follow all instructions). Check local tile distributors,the products are generally very reasonable in price.

One is by Miracle, "511 non-skid", a good product. Another I've used is Invisa Tread, not sure the manufacturer. Miracle is a reputable sealer company and I think it runs about 15$ a gallon (here).

Be careful around unfinished wood or metal, pull the strainer off your shower as well. Good Luck

Comment: Thanks mate. Any names for such products ? (So I can talk about them with the stores here in Australia)